# Python monkeypatch doesn't patch function correctly

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, monkeypatching

I'm trying to use `monkeypatch` to mock one public function but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Here's my file structure

```
myproject
  |-mrss
     |- feed_burner.py <- has get_feed()
     |- version_controller.py <- has get_version()
  |-tests
     |-feed_burner_tests.py
```

Here's my test

```
from mrss.feed_burner import get_feed
from _pytest.monkeypatch import monkeypatch


 def test_first_feed(self):
        mp = monkeypatch()
        mp.setattr(mrss.version_controller, 'get_version', lambda env: 7)
        mrss_feed = get_feed(env=get_config())
        root = ET.fromstring(mrss_feed)

        self.assertEquals(21, len(programmes))
```

And this is my get_feed function

```
from mrss.version_controller import get_version

def get_feed(env=os.environ):
    uploader = Uploader(env=env)
    folder = env.get('S3_FOLDER')

    version = get_version(env)
    print version.isdigit()
    print 'version is {v}'.format(v=str(version))
    if not version or not version.isdigit():
        return ''
```

And all I got for `get_version` is empty string

```
False
version is
```

I tried with this but no luck

```
with patch('mrss.feed_burner.get_feed.mrss.version_controller.get_version', new=lambda env: 7):
    mrss_feed = get_feed(env=get_config())
    root = ET.fromstring(mrss_feed)

    programmes = root.findall('programme')

    self.assertEquals(21, len(programmes))
```

Comment: Is the test in the same file as the definition of `get_feed`?

Comment: No. They are not in the same file. I'll update my full test

Comment: You are probably patching the wrong function. If `get_feed` is in a file `mycode.py`, then you need to patch `mycode.mrss.versioncontroller`, not `mrss.versioncontroller` imported into your test module. The `mock` module describes [what to patch](http://mock.readthedocs.org/en/latest/patch.html#where-to-patch), and I suspect you are experiencing the same problem (and the solution is the same, although I'm not sure enough to actually post an answer).

Comment: I tried with different location but nothing seems to work. I'll update my file structure and module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your test function,

```
from mrss.feed_burner import get_feed
from _pytest.monkeypatch import monkeypatch


def test_first_feed(self):
    mp = monkeypatch()
    mp.setattr(mrss.version_controller, 'get_version', lambda env: 7)
    mrss_feed = get_feed(env=get_config())
    root = ET.fromstring(mrss_feed)

    self.assertEquals(21, len(programmes))
```

the function object referenced by `get_feed` doesn't call `mrss.version_controller.get_version`, which is the reference used by your test module. It *really* calls `mrss.feed_burner.mrss.version_controller.get_version`, which is what you need to monkey patch. (`get_feed` has its own reference to its module scope, which is distinct from the reference in the test module.)